# JavaScript Alert on Specific Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, alert

How can I `alert` in javascript but only on any one specific page suppose, I want to alert "Hey!" but the problem is same hey is coming on other pages too after site loading, I want that Hey alert should be alert on homepage of my site now other pages.

Is it possible or sounds like crazy?

**Edit:** from comments: I have theme of wordpress on which homepage i'm working so wordpress generate html on run time i never saw html of it

Comment: yes you can do it, and you should be able to find the answer on google.

Comment: Is there anything on your homepage that identifies it as such?  eg `<div id='homepagecontainer'>`?  If so, you can check if that exists, such as `if ($("#homepagecontainer").length > 0) { alert("Hey!"); }`  [edit:fixed missing (]

Comment: @freedomn-m let me try this

Comment: You've obviously got the alert in a script that's included in all pages.  Just remove it from there and put it in the page itself, where you want it to show.

Comment: @freedomn-m only ID will work there not class?

Comment: *any* way to identify something on the homepage.  I only gave an example as IDs a unique.  If you have `<div class='homepage-wrapper'>` then, of course, use that.

Comment: Sorry @freedomn-m but that's a bad suggestion.  You're basically saying "include the code in all pages but only run it on one".  It would be better to only include it where it's needed.

Comment: @Archer I agree with you (I gave your comment a +1).  It may be *better* to only include the script where it's needed, but it's not the only solution.  I'm not saying "include the code in all pages", I'm answering the question of how to identify when the code is running on the homepage in the confines of the original context.

Comment: I understand, but in this instance I think it would definitely be better to address the cause of the problem or the OP will end up thinking that including it in all pages is correct, when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

**This is just for fun:** *(use in your case !)*

```
if( window.location.href.indexOf('stackoverflow.com/questions/47197404/javascript-alert-on-specific-page') !== -1 ) {
   alert('Hello world');
}
```

Ref: [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?

Like to you want to have a specific JS file called on the home page?

So do a enqueue_script for the home, put this code in your functions or in the plugin file:

```
if(is_home()) {
    function load_your_script() {
        wp_register_script('your_script_name_here', PATH/TO/YOUR/JS/FILE/HERE);
        wp_enqueue_script('your_script_name_here');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_your_script');
}
```

So that way, the JS file will be only loaded in your home.